# Wrap an AutoResetEvent object in a restricted WaitHandle?

Tags: c#, .net, waithandle, autoresetevent

I've built a library that launches a thread to do it's thing and returns a WaitHandle to the caller.

Looking at a bug report, I suspect the code that's calling my library is taking the returned object and casting it to an AutoResetEvent (which it is) and raising the flag itself. It's not meant to do that.

Is there a way I can wrap the AutoResetEvent object with one that can still be WaitOne'd and WaitAny'd, but can only be raised by my code?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not going to add this as an answer because it doesn't directly address your question... but a better solution might by to go back to the bug report and mark it as "intended behavior." It sounds like the consumers of your library are doing evil things they shouldn't be doing.

Comment: I thought about that, but they insist they're not doing that. But... the only way I can recreate the bug is by an unauthorised raising of the event at the wrong time. Diplomacy rules!

Comment: So you clearly got some multi-threaded code and works on your machine but doesn't work on another one.  That's normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new class derived from `EventWaitHandle` and override `Set` and `Reset` so they do nothing, or throw an exception. Actually, you would have to create `new` implementations, since `Set` and `Reset` aren't virtual. Of course, you'd have to create your own, other-named methods. Like `MyInternalSet` and `MyInternalReset`. Possible, but I wouldn't recommend doing it.

Instead I would document that the client should not set or reset the event, because doing so will cause unpredictable behavior.

You could create a `WaitHandle`-derived class that holds your `AutoResetEvent` as an `internal` property. Client code then wouldn't be able to access it. Something like:

```
public class MyWaitHandle: WaitHandle
{
    internal AutoResetEvent InternalEvent { get; private set; }
    internal MyWaitHandle(AutoResetEvent event)
    {
        InternalEvent = event;
    }

    public override bool WaitOne(int32 timeout)
    {
        return InternalEvent.WaitOne();
    }
}
```

You'll have to override the protected `Dispose(Boolean)` method, so that it will dispose the internal handle, and you'll want the other `WaitOne` overloads, as well. You can then create `internal` implementations of `Set` and `Reset`, or just have your code call `InternalHandle.Set`.

I still think the best course of action is to tell the client not to do that. But if you must prevent it, the above should work.

Comment: I wonder if WaitHandle.WaitAny will make use of my WaitOne overrides. Time to experiment! (Thanks for the in-depth answer.)